# Changing the order of data labels in Google Line Charts

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I have a line chart, along the lines of the below, and I want to be able to set which label is on top. (In the example, would want "dogs" to be on top.)

I realize I could do this manually -- just by switching the order of the columns -- but in practice I am dealing with large datasets and would much prefer to simply be able to specify the order in which the labels should appear on the axis without rearranging the columns themselves.

Is there any way to do that? I could not find it in the documentation.

Code example: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G2W868VK63KD

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable
            ([['X','dogs', 'cats'],
              [0, 1, 9],
              [1, 2, 7],
              [2, 3, 6],
              [3, 3, 9],
        ]);

        var options = {
          series: {
            0: { color: '#e2431e' },
            1: { color: '#e7711b' },
            2: { color: '#f1ca3a' },
            3: { color: '#6f9654' },
            4: { color: '#1c91c0' },
            5: { color: '#43459d' },
          }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are no config options available for setting the order.
but you could use a data view to change the order of the columns.

the `DataView` class has a method for `setColumns`,
which takes an array of column indexes.

```
view.setColumns([0, 2, 1, 4, 3]);
```

this could be done dynamically, by using an array to specify the order.

see following working snippet,
here, the `columnOrder` array is used to specify the order of the columns...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['X', 'cats', 'dogs', 'birds', 'reptiles', 'fish', 'rodents'],
    [0, 1, 9, 5, 8, 3, 2],
    [1, 2, 7, 3, 9, 4, 3],
    [2, 3, 6, 2, 10, 5, 4],
    [3, 3, 9, 5, 11, 6, 5],
  ]);

  // specify order
  var columnOrder = [
    'dogs',
    'birds',
    'cats',
    'fish',
    'rodents',
    'reptiles',
  ];

  // build data view columns
  var viewColumns = [0];
  columnOrder.forEach(function (label) {
    for (var i = 1; i < data.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
      if (data.getColumnLabel(i) === label) {
        viewColumns.push(i);
      }
    }
  });

  // build data view
  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns(viewColumns);

  var options = {
    height: 400,
    series: {
      0: { color: '#e2431e' },
      1: { color: '#e7711b' },
      2: { color: '#f1ca3a' },
      3: { color: '#6f9654' },
      4: { color: '#1c91c0' },
      5: { color: '#43459d' },
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(view, options);  // use view to draw chart
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```